# Multiple Kafka input not starting at the same time in Talend Job

Tags: apache-kafka, etl, talend

[image: Multiple Kafka input not starting at the same time in Talend Job]

I have a simple Talend standard job containing two Kafka inputs as you can see in the picture, the problem is when I run the job just one of the Kafka input start, the ideal condition that I expected to happen is multiple Kafka input running at the same time, is there is any configuration that I miss?

Answer (score 1):

[image]

you can easily add the tParallelize component at the beginning of the talend job and it will be executed at the same time, if you have multiple sub jobs it can work too.

I think the Talend job default runs in serial we just can't see which component runs first because the process is so fast.